# Excel Picture Link Dynamic Named Range

Tags: excel, linked-list, vlookup, named-ranges

I created a picture lookup function by pasting pictures into a table, created named ranges of each cell containing a picture, and used these named ranges as references in picture links locate on different sheets.

My problem now:

I'm trying to make the picture link references dynamic and dependeable on other cells/dropdowns/formulas containing/outputting the named range names.

The picture link e.g. references =C5 and cell C5 contains a list of named ranges, e.g. "Eggbasket".

If I reference cell c5 in the picture link it just displays a zoomed in picture of the cell (it just displays "EGGB.."). I apparently need something to make it realize that it's a named range. I tried =Indirect("C5") and =Indirect(C5) with no success. I get the following prompt "This formula is missing  a range reference or a defined name".

Greatful for any input, eager to learn a little piece more of the excel puzzle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a range name called `ShowPicture` and assign it the formula `=indirect(Sheet1!C5)` (adjust sheet name as required). Then point the dynamic image to the range name `ShowPicture'.

In the screenshots below, a Vlookup returns the range name associated with the cell that has the picture. The `showButton` range name then uses Indirect to create a reference to that picture. The dynamic image references `showButton'.

[image]

And again, with all moving parts:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! I initally thought I had tried that one before, but I had added quotation marks to the Indirect() function where they don't belong in my particular case.